# Front Controller implementation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, command

I have a front controller which receives all of the requests. Request has an action parameter which tells the controller which command to initiate.

Apparently Laravel commands are not supposed to return responses like views and redirects upon completion. Should my main controller do it? Different actions require different responses.

Perhaps I should implement command objects as tiny controllers with a single method like process()? If for example an action is to load a login screen, process() would simply return view('login'). Is that reasonable?

An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Job classes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#writing-job-classes

Your controller could dispatch a Job classs like this (like a tiny controller that you mentioned)...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue

The handle method on the Job class could return whatever you want to your controller.